# User Permissions and Undefined index: Notice messages

Tags: php, if-statement

On my site I have user groups setup to show different content based on what permission the user has.

Example here is my table:

[image]

The problem I'm getting is a bunch of notices stating:

- Undefined index: owner
- Undefined index: renter
- Undefined index: admin
- Undefined index: newuser
- Undefined index: nonuser

it says the're coming from classes\User.php on line 105

which is this:

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
                //$group = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = ?", array($this->data()->group_id));
        $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group_id));

        if($group->count()) {
            $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

            if($permissions[$key] == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Line 105 is this: `if($permissions[$key] == true) {`

When I call, for example, a different navigation to show up based on the users permission I do it like this:

```
<?php
$user = new User;


if($user->hasPermission('owner')) {
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/navs/owner-nav.php");
}

elseif($user->hasPermission('renter')) {
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/navs/renters-nav.php");
}

elseif($user->hasPermission('admin')) {
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/navs/admin-nav.php");
}

elseif($user->hasPermission('new')) {
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/navs/newuser-nav.php");
}

elseif (!$user->hasPermission('nonuser')){
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/navs/newuser-nav.php");
}
```

I get Notice messages for every permission except for the owner one because it's at the top of the list. If I put admin to the top of the list I don't get any Notices when I'm in admin mode and so on.

I don't understand why this is happening and was wondering if someone might have a solution.

I realize they are just notices and don't effect the site when I run it live, but it still throws an error file in my directory and just bugs me.

Anyways, if anyone has an idea or suggestion I would love to hear it.

Comment: `var_dump($permissions);` & check if key you pass actually exists.

Comment: Any reason you don't put it in a switch? And also ^^ above question

Comment: @Rikesh the key exists

Comment: @echo - Not always. Update your code as I suggested in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24200288/696364).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 105 to

```
if(isset($permissions[$key]) && $permissions[$key] == true)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use *[isset](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.isset.php)* to make sure that key really exists,

```
if(isset($permissions[$key]) && $permissions[$key] == true) {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that worked great. I've been at that forever thanks for clearing that up for me. You and colburton both came in at the same time with the correct answer. Do you mind if I give the answer to him as he has less rep points than you..?